# Sound file location isn't found when run in another computer

Tags: c#

My C# program is running well on my computer and the sound is playing, but when i sent it to my lecturer, he said the program was running but it couldn't locate my sound file. my file location in the program was like:

`C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Barista3000_Aroka_Lab6\Barista3000_skal\Sounds\sound.wav`

How do i make sure the sound will always be located when ran on a different computer?

Comment: Try to include the sound file in to the project

Comment: how do you locate the file in your code? Do you use relative path?

Comment: Hi bit! i have a folder in my project called 'sounds', where i store the sound files. it's found when ran on my comp, but not when moved to another computer. I zipped the whole project folder and sent it to the lecturer, and the sound folder is in the project folder..

Comment: Hi kennyzx!, i'm not sure about the relative path. how does it work?

Comment: You have two options: Include the file in the exe, which will be simple and reliable but also not flexible and will blow up the exe. Or you can use a path that works and any machine. Here the real question is: where should it be? If you want to keep it with the exe set the path to something like this: `.\yoursound.wav`, which is a relative path (becaus the dot says start here, as opposed to an absolute path starting with a `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the file to your project like and set build action to content.
[image]

And when you build the project it will end up in your output folder, just play it with something like.

```
PlayFile("sound.wav"); // I made up this method btw.
```

Notice, not the full path to the file, this is relative and it will look for this file in the working (current) folder.

> How do i make sure the sound will always be located when ran on a different computer?

For this, you will still need to distribute it with your EXE and other 'stuff' that's in your build output folder.

Also, have a look at embedding resources, that way you can include the WAV in your EXE.

Comment: Thank you guys for your input. I'll do as advised then get back. Good day.

Comment: Just trying to fix it now, but i can't seem to see my sound files through Visual studio solution Explorer, the files are stored in the folder called sounds. for some reason i can only see one sound file through solution Explorer, while the rest 3 are not visisble. what's the problem.

Comment: click the 

`show all files` and then rightclick and select `include in project`

or right click on the folder and select `Add -> Existing Item` and select your file(s)

Comment: Thanks Drake! i can now see the files. But i still have a problem with this relative path. I can play the sounds, but not sure they'll play when moved to Another computer. In my code, i have the path as follows: C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Barista3000_Aroka_Lab6\Barista3000_skal\Sounds\Sparkling Water Sound.wav

Comment: if you make it part of the output and make sure that when you copy the files your include all the files, EXE, DLLS and WAVS

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean as part of the output. As you can see, the wav file is in the Sounds folder which is in the Project folder. However, i changed the sound properties; Build Action to 'Content'; Copy to output directory to 'copy if newer'. In this case is it ok after running build, to change the path to just show the filename? hope you get me.

Comment: Copy to output and build action content will place the file in the BIN folder, so `PlayFile('sound.wav')` will work, it will not place it in a sub folder.

Comment: I did exactly that, the folder was copied to bin folder, i changed the path to just SoundPlayer("soundfile.wav"), and when i ran it, it could NOT locate the file. Really frustrating. Any idea?